# PHP5 How to build a class with a starting array?

Tags: php, arrays, class, menu, menuitem

I have a problem in constructing a Menu, I'd like to create a class like this:

```
class leftMenu{

public $items;

    function addItem ($num){

        for($i = 0; $i < count($num); $i++){
              $this->items[$i] += $num;
              echo $this->items[$i];
            }

    }

public function __destruct() {
      //echo "\n</body>\n</html>";
    }

}
```

I'd like to call the addItem like an array, example:

```
$menu = new leftMenu();
$menu->addItem("one", "two", "three"); // Here 1, 2, 3 should be an array
```

I can't make it work... Please help!!!
ND

Comment: You either need to pass in an array, or use [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your code in the following way ( i just initialized the variable $items ,and one other edit which you can see in the comments):

```
class leftMenu{

public $items = array();  //intialize your variable $items

    function addItem ($num){

        for($i = 0; $i < count($num); $i++){
              $this->items[$i] = $num[$i]; //Edit this line too
              echo $this->items[$i];
            }

    }

public function __destruct() {
      //echo "\n</body>\n</html>";
    }

}
```

And when you call it, pass an array to it like this:

```
$menu = new leftMenu();
$menu->addItem(array("one", "two", "three")); // Here 1, 2, 3 should be an array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = array("one", "two", "three");

$menu->addItems($items);


function addItems($items = array()) {
  $this->items = $items;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass in the variables as an array. Try this:

$menu->addItem(array("one", "two", "three"));